# Why <nav> element is converted to a block level element?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

why do you think `<nav>` element is converted to a block level element in bootstrap?
Originally it is inline element.

Answer (score 1):

It is a [block-level element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/nav.html). Bootstrap probably specifies that explicitly to force older browsers to render it correctly, as they will render unknown tags as inline elements.

Comment: where can you see it is a block-level element? So this is list is wrong? http://www.tutorialchip.com/tutorials/inline-elements-list-whats-new-in-html5/

Comment: @tirengarfio: Yep, it's wrong. The default style should be `display: block`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/nav.html